# MessageBox from BackgroundWorker not visible

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, messagebox

For my desktop app I've implemented a custom progress bar which performs long running tasks asynchronously (and reports back the progress, of course).

my main app calls (simplified):

```
myForm aProgress = new myForm(<some_params>);
aProgress.ShowDialog();
```

the form's constructor (simplified):

```
BackgroundWorker myWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
myWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(<some_async_stuff>);
```

and form's load event handler:

```
myWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

During the process *some_async_stuff* needs to display a MessageBox and wait for the user to respond (yes/no). Invoke is used to **force** the MessageBox to appear **in front of** the progress bar form:

```
if ((DialogResult)Invoke((Func<DialogResult>)(() => { return MessageBox.Show("question", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo); })) == DialogResult.No)
    <something>;
else
    <something_else>;
```

**The problem:**

In most cases EVERYTHING (including the MessageBox and user's response) works as expected. However SOMETIMES the MessageBox simply won't appear, yet the application is waiting for user's response (indefinitely, of course).

This behavior is hard to reproduce reliably, happens occasionally.
Any thoughts or similar experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar example is available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If you need to use a messagebox, it's not a background process. Don't use a BackgroundWorker to interact with the user.

Comment: Otherwise, rather than invoking the MessageBox, you would have to consider the task (partially) completed, return to the UI thread, and take steps to continue with part 2 (or 3) of the task, maintaining the partial state in between.